# JQuery combine attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript that I am working on and I would like to combine two selectors so that they refer to this tag only:

```
<input name="checkable" type="checkbox">
```

So that only checkable with type checkbox will react to it while a text-field with a name of *checkable* will not.  I have tried:

```
$("input[name='checkable' type='checkbox']")
```

with no success.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: BTW: Do you have multiple input elements with the same [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#control-name) but of different `type`?

Comment: Yes they have the same name one is a checkbox one is a text field

Comment: Roger that :) Just making sure that this was actually the right approach.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$("input[name='checkable'][type='checkbox']")
```

Cf. [Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

Comment: Thx! this helped me to avoid do innecesary loops.